Maven wildfly plugin java util logging fine
The maven wildfly plugin v4.2.1.Final is not able to log the Level.FINE and below using the java.util.logging package. I tried following the documentation here but there is no link for java.util.logging . Following the steps on that page is giving me the below error when the configuration.cli script is run.
Specific problem or error
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:4.2.1.Final:dev (default-cli) on project jakartaee: Failed to execute commands: The command is not available in the current context (e.g. required subsystems or connection to the controller might be unavailable).

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to execute commands: The command is not available in the current context (e.g. required subsystems or connection to the controller might be unavailable).


Complete large error log is here or partial is below.
[DEBUG] Provider org.wildfly.security.sasl.gs2.WildFlyElytronSaslGs2Provider not found.
[DEBUG] Provider org.wildfly.security.sasl.gssapi.WildFlyElytronSaslGssapiProvider not found.
[DEBUG] Provider org.wildfly.security.sasl.oauth2.WildFlyElytronSaslOAuth2Provider not found.
[DEBUG] Provider org.wildfly.security.sasl.otp.WildFlyElytronSaslOTPProvider not found.
[DEBUG] Provider org.wildfly.security.sasl.plain.WildFlyElytronSaslPlainProvider not found.
[DEBUG] Provider org.wildfly.security.sasl.scram.WildFlyElytronSaslScramProvider not found.
[DEBUG] Unable to create instance
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SaslClientFactory (provider: WildFlyElytron) cannot be found.
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass (Provider.java:2007)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getDefaultConstructor (Provider.java:2023)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceOf (Provider.java:1937)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceUtil (Provider.java:1945)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance (Provider.java:1920)
    at org.wildfly.security.WildFlyElytronProvider$ProviderService.newInstance (WildFlyElytronProvider.java:289)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.SecurityProviderSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient (SecurityProviderSaslClientFactory.java:94)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient (AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.java:66)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.ProtocolSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient (ProtocolSaslClientFactory.java:50)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient (AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.java:66)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.ServerNameSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient (ServerNameSaslClientFactory.java:50)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient (AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.java:66)

Project Tree
mavenLog
├── pom.xml
├── configure-logging.cli
├── remove-logging.cli
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── org
        │       └── eclipse
        │           └── jakarta
        │               └── servlet
        │                   ├── Echo1Servlet.java
        │                   └── Echo2Servlet.java
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── web.xml

configure-logging.cli
# Start the embedded server
embed-server

# let the console display TRACE logs
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level, value=TRACE)

# create the logger for our code (with the name org.wildfly.examples corresponding to our package)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.wildfly.examples:add(level=TRACE)
stop-embedded-server

Pom.xml
Shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem or project is here or relevant pom.xml is below.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>jakartaee-hello-world</name>
    <description>
        This is a very simple Jakarta EE application generated by the official Eclipse Starter.
    </description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.report.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.report.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <jakartaee-api.version>10.0.0</jakartaee-api.version>
        <wildfly.version>30.0.1.Final</wildfly.version>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <war-plugin.version>3.4.0</war-plugin.version>
        <wildfly-plugin.version>4.2.1.Final</wildfly-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>jakartaee-hello-world</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Execute 'mvn clean package wildfly:dev' to run the application. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${wildfly-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>${wildfly.version}</version>
                    <server-config>standalone-full.xml</server-config>
                    <!-- Execute the script in offline mode -->
                    <offline>true</offline>
                    <scripts>
                        <script>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}/configuration.cli</script>
                    </scripts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Jdk version ? wildfly version ? your full example project ?

The command is not available in the current context (e.g. required subsystems or connection to the controller might be unavailable) ... ?

OpenJDK v21.0.4, I am using the Jakarta example from here . Not sure how to check the wildfly version, the maven plugin is v4.2.1.Final ,,,, @life888888 ...

@khmarbaise ... Please bear with me as I am relatively new to the ecosystem. mvn clean package wildfly:dev -X is the command I am running on a local setup.

sample project here

I would recommend to upgrade your wildfly-maven-plugin to the most recent version https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/releases/5.0/ ...

No luck with the 5.0.1.Final as well, the server version WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 30.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 22.0.2.Final)

Did you get a better error message with 5.0.1.Final? Can you past your plugin configuration? FWIW the for logging will not work as that is for logging in the container, not from Maven. Typically with Maven you'd use -X to see debug information, but it will be a lot of info.

Sorry for not pasting this earlier, the pom is here , the error message is really huge and I have uploaded it here .

Kindly add all the debugging details/code in description in addition to linking the code(which you have already done) so that this can helpful for future readers. Great example of how to do that is https://stackoverflow.com/a/79025622/2073920

Project Tree
base on your sample project (https://github.com/ragavendra/mavenLog)
mavenLog
├── pom.xml
├── configure-logging.cli
├── remove-logging.cli
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── org
        │       └── eclipse
        │           └── jakarta
        │               └── servlet
        │                   ├── Echo1Servlet.java
        │                   └── Echo2Servlet.java
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── web.xml

update pom.xml
Update1:
<wildfly-plugin.version>5.0.0.Final</wildfly-plugin.version>

Add:
<!--  jboss-logging API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>jakartaee-hello-world</name>
    <description>
        This is a very simple Jakarta EE application generated by the official Eclipse Starter.
    </description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.report.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.report.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <jakartaee-api.version>10.0.0</jakartaee-api.version>
        <wildfly.version>30.0.1.Final</wildfly.version>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <war-plugin.version>3.4.0</war-plugin.version>
        <!--
        <wildfly-plugin.version>4.2.1.Final</wildfly-plugin.version>
        -->
        <wildfly-plugin.version>5.0.0.Final</wildfly-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  jboss-logging API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>jakartaee-hello-world</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Execute 'mvn clean package wildfly:dev' to run the application. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${wildfly-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>${wildfly.version}</version>
                    <server-config>standalone-full.xml</server-config>
                    <!-- Execute the script in offline mode -->
                    <offline>true</offline>
                    <scripts>
                        <script>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}/configuration.cli</script>
                    </scripts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

configure-logging.cli
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.eclipse.jakarta:add(level=TRACE)

remove-logging.cli
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.eclipse.jakarta:remove

web.xml
<web-app version="6.0"
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>Echo1Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Echo1Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo1Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Echo1Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/echo1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>Echo2Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Echo2Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Echo2Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/echo2</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Echo1Servlet.java
use org.jboss.logging.Logger
UPDATE: ADD logger.log(Level.FINE, "FINE log here 2");
package org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Echo1Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Echo1Servlet.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Echo1Servlet() {
        super();
        logger.info("Echo1Servlet()");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("doGet Served at: " + request.getContextPath());
        
        String msg = request.getParameter("msg");
        logger.info("msg = " + msg);
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath()).append("\nmsg=" + msg);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("doPost Served at: " + request.getContextPath());

        String msg = request.getParameter("msg");
        logger.info("msg = " + msg);
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath()).append("\nmsg=" + msg);

    }

}

Echo2Servlet.java
use java.util.logging.Logger
package org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Echo2Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Echo2Servlet.class.getName());
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getName());

    public Echo2Servlet() {
        super();
        logger.info("Echo2Servlet()");
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "FINE log here 1"); // NOT WORKING , WHEN ROOT LEVEL IS INFO.
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("doGet Served at: " + request.getContextPath());
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "FINE log here 2"); // NOT WORKING , WHEN ROOT LEVEL IS INFO.

        String msg = request.getParameter("msg");
        logger.info("msg = " + msg);
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath()).append("\nmsg=" + msg);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("doPost Served at: " + request.getContextPath());
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "FINE log here 3"); // NOT WORKING , WHEN ROOT LEVEL IS INFO.

        String msg = request.getParameter("msg");
        logger.info("msg = " + msg);
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath()).append("\nmsg=" + msg);
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}

config environment variable

Download wildfly-30.0.1.Final.tar.gz and unzip it.

Use JDK 17.

Edit .bashrc


nano ~/.bashrc


add environment variable WILDFLY_HOME

export WILDFLY_HOME=/your-path/wildfly-30.0.1.Final

Start Wildfly
cd $WILDFLY_HOME/bin
./standalone.sh

deploy to wildfly
mvn wildfly:deploy

Test
Test 1 - Echo1Servlet - org.jboss.logging.Logger
curl http://localhost:8080/jakartaee-hello-world/echo1?msg=Hello

Test 2 - Echo1Servlet - org.jboss.logging.Logger
curl -X POST -d "msg=Hello" http://localhost:8080/jakartaee-hello-world/echo1

Test 3 - Echo2Servlet - java.util.logging.Logger
curl http://localhost:8080/jakartaee-hello-world/echo2?msg=Hello

Test 4 - Echo2Servlet - java.util.logging.Logger
curl -X POST -d "msg=Hello" http://localhost:8080/jakartaee-hello-world/echo2

Check Output
wildfly-30.0.1.Final/standalone/log
server.log
2024-09-26 12:53:13,412 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo1Servlet] (default task-1) Echo1Servlet()
2024-09-26 12:53:13,412 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo1Servlet] (default task-1) doGet Served at: /jakartaee-hello-world
2024-09-26 12:53:13,412 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo1Servlet] (default task-1) msg = Hello
2024-09-26 12:53:19,903 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo1Servlet] (default task-1) doPost Served at: /jakartaee-hello-world
2024-09-26 12:53:19,906 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo1Servlet] (default task-1) msg = Hello
2024-09-26 12:54:58,597 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) Echo2Servlet()
2024-09-26 12:54:58,597 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) doGet Served at: /jakartaee-hello-world
2024-09-26 12:54:58,598 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) msg = Hello
2024-09-26 12:55:03,037 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) doPost Served at: /jakartaee-hello-world
2024-09-26 12:55:03,038 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) msg = Hello
2024-09-26 12:55:03,038 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) doGet Served at: /jakartaee-hello-world
2024-09-26 12:55:03,038 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) msg = Hello

UPDATE:
logger.log(Level.FINE, "FINE log here 2");
NOT WORKING , WHEN ROOT LEVEL IS INFO (Default).
Run Config:
$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:9990 --file=configure-logging.cli


Run Test Command Again:
curl http://localhost:8080/jakartaee-hello-world/echo2?msg=Hello

curl -X POST -d "msg=Hello" http://localhost:8080/jakartaee-hello-world/echo2

Check Log:
wildfly-30.0.1.Final/standalone/log/server.log
2024-09-27 09:55:49,839 FINE  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) FINE log here 1
2024-09-27 09:55:49,839 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) doGet Served at: /jakartaee-hello-world
2024-09-27 09:55:49,839 FINE  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) FINE log here 2
2024-09-27 09:55:49,839 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) msg = Hello
2024-09-27 09:55:57,407 INFO  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) doPost Served at: /jakartaee-hello-world
2024-09-27 09:55:57,408 FINE  [org.eclipse.jakarta.servlet.Echo2Servlet] (default task-1) FINE log here 3

IF FINISH TEST, REMOVE LOGGING CONFIG:
$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:9990 --file=remove-logging.cli


in conclusion:

(1) There is no special configuration configuration.cli, so org.eclipse.jakarta is not seen in the management interface. (ONLY WORK FOR LOG LEVEL IS INFO) (UPDATE)

(2) Using org.jboss.logging.Logger or java.util.logging.Logger can output logging to Wildfly’s server.log

(3) Only focus on the key points to be tested, so I added simple Echo1Servlet and Echo2Servlet to do simple log tests

(4) ADD LOG CONFIGUARTION TRACE (UPDATE)



Can you add a log line with java util logging or in Echo2Servlet.java like this logger.log(Level.FINE, "FINE log here "); and confirm if it is working? Info log worked fine on the console.

I updated the answer. By default, LOG CONFIG is not added. LOG FINE will not be added to LOG because ROOT LEVEL is INFO. So I manually executed the command and added LOG CONFIGURATION.

thanks for your answer. I was able to log the FINE as well by just adding /subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level, value=TRACE) . The guide might have to be updated accordingly. @life888888
